# Angular Hottowel crashing Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So have successful built the Hottowel Angular build via command line and now trying to run via opening website with Visual Studio 2013, but no matter what, VS crashes. Have read the post from John Papa's thread about others having the issue, but no fix that has worked. It does open if I remove the node modules and I believe this to be an issue with path character length. Am hoping some of you here can point in the right direction. Any thoughts on this? The thread I am referring to is: http://www.johnpapa.net/get-up-and-running-with-node-and-visual-studio/

Thoughts please?

Thanks much

Comment: Can anyone add to this? Only thing I have found is if I hide the folder where 'node_modules' exists, it is fine. There has to be a better work around though?